# Drag and drop, then reading addresses of file into textboxes

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

Here is what I have done so far for this:

```
private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.BackColor = Color.Sienna;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));

        string Horizontal = null;
        string Vertical = null;

        for (int i = 0x24; i <= 0x25; i++)
        {
            br.BaseStream.Position = i;
            Horizontal += br.ReadByte().ToString("X2");
        }
        for (int i = 0x26; i <= 0x27; i++)
        {
            br.BaseStream.Position = i;
            Vertical += br.ReadByte().ToString("X2");
        }
        br.Close();

        string hexvalue = Horizontal;
        string hexvalue1 = Vertical;

        int decValue = Convert.ToInt32(hexvalue, 16);
        int decValue1 = Convert.ToInt32(hexvalue1, 16);

        textBox1.Text = ("" + decValue);
        textBox2.Text = ("" + decValue1);
    }
```

I am trying to support the ability to drag and drop a file into the panel, then with BinaryReader, read the data from the addresses in the file I dropped, into the textboxes.

This works when clicking a button every time with OpenFileDialog, but drag and drop is far quicker.

I tried running the program and encountered an issue with BinaryReader when loading the file I dropped. It worked with OpenFileDialog though. But how can I make dropping a file into the panel, function just like when opening the file from a button?

Comment: Where are you accessing the dropped file? It seems you are defining a drop handle, but then start reading from whatever ofd is, independent of e.Data. What I would expect is you to extract the dropped file path, and then initialize the reader with that. You should also consider putting your reader and its operations in a using{}

Comment: Have a look on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cipKJ2a6r8s) he is almost doing the same as you. Please pay attention how he extracts the filenames from `e.Data`.

Comment: NB: If you use the e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop,false); call where e is the drageventargs reference, the returned object can be cast into a string[], containing the paths of all dropped filesystem entities, directory or file.

Comment: Thanks for the video. I am very new to C# so I'll definitely need to understand a bit more before I ask another question. What I was wanting to do was drop a file into the program. Then it reads the file and outputs what is in the address I specified it to read. It outputs it as hex converted to decimal form in the 2 textboxes I made in the form.

Comment: Make sure you enabled the [AllowDrop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.allowdrop(v=vs.110).aspx) property for the panel.